Is there an analogous Unruh effect for observers on a rigidly rotating ring?
I read up on the Unruh effect recently and what I got from it is that its basically a result of transforming to Rindler coordinates and using a Bogoliubov transformation to change the creation and annihilation operators and therefore the number operator. Thus instead of being a vacuum, the observer experiences a thermal bath.
I was wondering if we could use Born coordinates so Langevin observers? Would they experience a heat bath? And would this be any different than just finding the "relativistic centripetal acceleration"?

I never saw a calculation like this. My guess is that you most likely see particles (99% sure of that), but I wouldn't expect a thermal spectrum at all

There is a claimed connection between the depolarization of a beam circulating in a cyclotron and the Unruh temperature: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0550321387900472
